# Sort info from .txt to four different arrays (both int's and strings)

Tags: java, arrays, import

(Improved question from earlier)
So I have this assignment that I'm part way stuck on, I need to start it off by adding information to different arrays about hurricanes from one text document (hurcdata.txt). I understand you should use for loops, but can you give me an example or a good answer please? The "month" array in the below code ends up adding all parts of the document, not just the months.

Oh and if you could (and if it's possible) could you give the answer using for-each loops? Thank you so much!

Variables and imports:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
//declare and initialize variables


int arrayLength = 59;
int [] year = new int[arrayLength];
String [] month = new String[arrayLength];
int [] pressure = new int[arrayLength];
double [] windSpeed = new double[arrayLength];
String [] hurcName = new String[arrayLength];

File fileName = new File("/Users/jerome/Desktop/hurcdata.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
```

And here's my attempt at adding the text file to the arrays:

```
//INPUT  - read data in from the file
int index = 0;
while (inFile.hasNext())
{
    month[index] = inFile.next();
    index++;
}

while (inFile.hasNext())
{
    pressure[index] = inFile.nextInt();
    index++;
}
inFile.close();
```

Sample data from hurcdata.txt:

```
1980 Aug 945 100 Allen
1983 Aug 962 100 Alicia
1984 Sep 949 100 Diana
1985 Jul 1002 65 Bob
1985 Aug 987 80 Danny
1985 Sep 959 100 Elena
```

...

Comment: Oh please don't do that. Use classes and objects, the basics of encapsulation.

Comment: Complex importing from files can get tricky, and yes: it is recommended to follow OOP principles.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int item:month)
month[item] = infile.next();
```

Like this you can do for all of your arrays